# How to get data from node.js server into Electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My question is about:

I am currently trying to connect my electron application to my node server to get data from node.js server and print that data to my electron application. However I don't know how to do it. So could anyone help me:

To get data from node.js server into electron app?

Comment: electron also surport `nodejs`, so you can get data by `nodejs` module, or `javascript` like `xhr` or other libary to do this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The way you get data from any node.js server is you make a request to that server specifying in the request what you're asking for and the server responds with the appropriate data.

There are literally thousands of ways to physically make the request.  The classic way in these days of web technologies is to make an http request from your electron app to an http server in your node.js server.  You can make such a request from electron using the [`request()` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

You would then have an http server as part of your node.js server and you'd specify routes in that http server that handle the requests your electron client is making, fetch the desired data and send the data back as the response.  In the node.js world, you can create a simple http server and a few request handlers in a dozen lines of code using the Express library.

This is the general approach.  Further details on the exact request to make and URLs to use are dependent upon the details of what you're trying to do and the design you choose, none of which you've shared with us.